# Ignore pattern errors in a regex search and do not crash the search

Tags: c#, regex

I am working on a regex search and replace program and would like to have a real-time preview that shows any change immediately.

My problem is that the program logically crashes when I open a "[" bracket, for example, because Regex expects a bracket to be closed. Of course, there may be other errors where the program crashes during a search.

I would like to stop the search and display an error message if the pattern is wrong.

Does anyone know of a solution to use an "IF" query in C#, for example, to check if a regex search would work before executing it?

Or how else can I get by without crashing?

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public string UseRegex(string input, string search, string replace)
{
    if (???)
    {
        string result = Regex.Replace(input, search, replace);
        return result;
    }
    else
    {
        return "error";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
public string UseRegex(string input, string search, string replace)
{
   try
   {
      string result = Regex.Replace(input, search, replace);
      return result;
   }
   catch
   {
      return input;
   }
}
```

Comment: It worked after all, beware of the debug program, it doesn't seem to use the try/catch properly..

TY